# Get Element Height from Using insertAdjacentHTML inout HTML

Tags: javascript

I just used insertAdjacentHTML to input a HTML DOM that got from fetch:

in a.html:

```
<div class="header-box"><h1 class="title">This is Title</h1></div>
```

in b.html:

```
fetch('a.html').then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.text();
    }

    throw new Error('Got Error!');
}).then((data) => {
    document.querySelector('#main').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', data);
    const titleHeight = document.querySelector('.title').offsetHeight;
    console.log(titleHeight);
});
```

But I got an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight'
>   of null at eval

How should I do to get the height?
Thanks.

Comment: Escape the single quote here: `throw new Error('Can't Get Data!');`.

Comment: Sorry! I have change this, because it's not my question.